# ffmpeg on fb0 from Nexus Galaxy error: "could not get frame filename number 2"

Tags: android, ffmpeg, adb

I use ffmpeg to convert fb0 files from Androids and produce screenshots.  For some reason this does not work with the Nexus Galaxy.

I get this error:

```
[image2 @ 0000000001E0E350] Could not get frame filename number 2 from pattern '
image.png'
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid argument
```

Here is the process:

```
    C:\dev\scripts>adb pull /dev/graphics/fb0
3292 KB/s (16777216 bytes in 4.976s)

C:\dev\scripts>ffmpeg -vframes 1 -vcodec rawvideo -f rawvideo -pix
_fmt rgb32 -s 720x1080 -i fb0 -f image2 -vcodec png image.png
ffmpeg version N-36635-gceb0dd9 Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jan  9 2012 17:45:55 with gcc 4.6.2
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-ru
ntime-cpudetect --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-frei0r --enable-libope
ncore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --en
able-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger -
-enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwben
c --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-
libxvid --enable-zlib
  libavutil      51. 34.100 / 51. 34.100
  libavcodec     53. 54.100 / 53. 54.100
  libavformat    53. 29.100 / 53. 29.100
  libavdevice    53.  4.100 / 53.  4.100
  libavfilter     2. 58.100 /  2. 58.100
  libswscale      2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libswresample   0.  6.100 /  0.  6.100
  libpostproc    51.  2.100 / 51.  2.100
[rawvideo @ 000000000037D5A0] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inac
curate
Input #0, rawvideo, from 'fb0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (BGRA / 0x41524742), bgra, 720x1080, 25 tbr, 25
 tbn, 25 tbc
[buffer @ 000000000037D420] w:720 h:1080 pixfmt:bgra tb:1/1000000 sar:0/1 sws_pa
ram:
Output #0, image2, to 'image.png':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf53.29.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: png, bgra, 720x1080, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo -> png)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[image2 @ 0000000001E0E350] Could not get frame filename number 2 from pattern '
image.png'
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid argument
```

Answer (score 11):

If you converting rawvideo to image format there may be more than one image.  Ffmpeg is just warning you that the output filename is not in the appropriate format it needs to output multiple image files.

Try this instead:

ffmpeg -vframes 1 -vcodec rawvideo -f rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb32 -s 720x1080 -i fb0 -f image2 -vcodec png image_%05d.png

This should produce several image files, i.e.:

image_00001.png
image_00002.png
image_00003.png
...

Comment: is ffmpeg confused ? if the command reads `-vframes 1`, why does ffmpeg need `frame filename number 2` ? i have the same error - and i dont like to add '01' to all my filenames ...

Comment: Option vframes (set the number of video frames to output) cannot be applied to input url fb0 -- you are trying to apply an input option to an output file or vice versa.